# Getting python-jenkins error though I have latest pip and python versions and have installed python-jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I have this task in my playbook to get the status of passed jenkins jobs

```
- jenkins_job_facts:
    color: green
    user: "{{jenkinsuid}}"
    password: "{{jenkinspwd}}"
  register: jenkins_status
```

I am getting the below error for the above task:

```
"fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "python-jenkins required for this module.
see http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html"}"
```

I have these installed in my mac:

```
Ansible 2.7.0dev0
pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
Python 2.7.10
Python 3.6.5
jankinsapi 0.3.6
```

And got the below message after installing python-jenkins:

```
"Successfully installed certifi-2018.4.16 chardet-3.0.4 multi-key-dict-2.0.3 pbr-4.0.3 python-jenkins-1.0.0 requests-2.18.4 urllib3-1.22"
```

I did an extensive online search and tried various options... I could not solve this issue yet.  Am I missing something here?

Could it be an issue if I would have both python 2.7.10 & 3.6.5 versions (If it is yes then please let me know the steps to remove both python versions completely and install the latest version 3.6.5)?

Comment: Ansible uses `/usr/bin/python` by default. Which version is that for you? If it's not 2.7, try setting `ansible_python_interpreter` as described on http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#ansible-python-interpreter

Comment: I have actually set up ansible_python_interpreter in my playbook to the default python3 path, which is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

Comment: Have you tried `import jenkins` in Python 3? If that doesn't work, try with `/usr/bin/python`. Maybe `pip` installed `python-jenkins` somewhere unknown to Python 3.

Comment: /usr/bin/python did not work. As I am working on Ansible code, do we configure "Import jenkins" somewhere for Python 3 (I am not using any python code)?